# R - Adding a color legend to a plot of polygons (with predefined colors)

Tags: r, plot, polygon, legend

I want to add a color scale legend to a plot I have created with polygons where the fill color of each polygon is predetermined.

The image below are my polygons and the code below is what I use to generate my plot (if there is a better way to code this please advise).

[image]

```
plot(alldata[alldata[,3]==forceIds[50],1:2], col="orange", type='l', xlim=range(alldata[,1]),ylim=range(alldata[,2]))
for(i in 1:length(forceIds)){
  polygon(x=alldata[alldata[,3]==forceIds[i],1],y=alldata[alldata[,3]==forceIds[i],2], col=A3$Key2[i])
}
```

alldata is my dataset with all the polygons, forceIds are the unique list of polygons, A3 is a table with my predefined colors (output of colors from an earlier heatmap).

I want to add a color scale legend to the bottom of each graph, labeled "Good - Bad"?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you intend to present an identical colour scale to each plot? It may be better to just provide it once, e.g. to the side of the three plots.

Comment: Hi @jbaums, I want three separate color scales one for each plot.  You you can share how I can append in on the side altering the above code that would be great?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this can get you started. You'll need to replace the colour ramps with the A3 table colours.

```
# create a 6 plot layout, with a tall top row and narrow bottom row
layout(mat=matrix(data = 1:6, nrow = 2, byrow=T), heights=c(3,1))

# standard left, bottom, top and right margins
par(mar=c(5,4,4,2)+0.1)
for (i in 1:3) { plot(1:3) }

# reduce the size of the top margin so the plots and colour bars are closer
par(mar=c(5,4,1,2)+0.1)

# create a matrix coding the values 1 (Bad) to 10 (Good)
m = matrix(data = 1:10, ncol = 1)

# plot 3 colour bars and add custom axis
for (i in 1:3) {
    image(x = 1:10, y = 1, z = m,
          col=colorRampPalette(c('orange', 'red'))(10),
          axes=F, xlab='', ylab='')
    axis(3, at=c(1,10), labels = c('Bad', 'Good'))
}
```

Comment: Thanks @koekenbakker I was successfully able to alter the above to give me what I was looking for.

Comment: That's great. If you decide to plot only one scale, you can simply modify the `layout`.